# Looking for an old animated movie with 4 superpowered characters

Tags: story-identification

So this movie is about 3 guys and 1 girl flying around in space in a big spaceship, and they all have their own "power" and they have different ways of acquiring them. One guy's suit is green and white, the other dude's is red and white and I can't remember the third. As for the girl, I think she is a princess or something, I believe she could read minds and control them. They also have each own smaller spaceship they use for when they are going down to a planet to "kill the threat".

The guy in the green suit is short and fat and likes to eat a lot.
The guy in the red and white suit is the head character and possibly the strongest of them all. He has this headband thing, that he does something to, then it starts glowing and his powers emerge and transforms him, giving him full bodyarmor like a spacesuit.
The other male character is tall and skinny, I can't remember the color of his suit though.

In some part of this movie they come to a "crystal galaxy thing" where they fight an "ice crystal princess" or something like that. It's very hard to be super specific, cause I feel like I know a lot about this movie, but then again it was like 20 years since I saw it the first time.

I remember the box for this VHS was white and a little bigger than all the other boxes, if that's any help.

Comment: Not Centurions then? https://cliqueypizza.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/the-centurians-comic-cover.jpg - http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xs0b21_centurions-02-battle-beneath-the-sea_shortfilms

Comment: Ah yes, i thought so too at first, but it's not, the "headcharacter" looks like a teenager. Thanks for replying tho!

Comment: So what are these powers?

Comment: Well the "headcharacter" has this headband thing, with a crystal in it, so he does something, then it starts glowing, then platingstuff comes out of it and he gets like a full body armor and a combatstaff or something like that.

Comment: Some of your description reminds me of Battle of the Planets, which is a recut of the anime series Science Ninja Team Gatchaman. It was a TV series, though, and there were five people. The Gatchaman entry on wikipedia says there were a couple of movies, so perhaps it's one of them?

Comment: Yeah the thing is, everything fits pretty good with Gatchaman, but i'm positive they where only 4 in this movie I had, but a friend told me, this movie might be a series cut into a movie, so idk if it acutally is a movie now lol..

Comment: I think I remember this, it was a jewel in one of the kids' headband that made armor appear on his body.  It was him and his sister, who had the mind powers, along with a Han Solo-type character who was leading them around.  I thought it was more fantasy than sci-fi.

Comment: I was near certain it was [G-Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-Force:_Guardians_of_Space), oh well.

Comment: @Alan Do you know of a connection between Battle of the Planets and Starzinger?   The 4 characters in Starzinger are near exact matches to BotP characters down to body type appearance and costume colors.  Even to both girls being "Princess".

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I've never heard of Starzinger before. A quick investigation shows that they don't have any creative staff in common. I'd bet that Starzinger is taking the popular Gatchaman style and applying it to the Journey to the West in a sort of mashup/rip-off. (Weirdly, two of the character names sound awfully like those of the Three Musketeers, which makes me think the translators must have been trying to put it into the mix too.)

Answer (score 11):

After looking for this anime for seriously 20 years, I finally managed to google it! (Lemme tell you, I ran across several threads asking the same question: "can anyboy tell me the name of this anime with 3 guys in different colored suits where one has a mace for a weapon." No answer. Hehe. Everybody in Sweden seems to have watched this anime in the '90s.) Anyway, without further ado: [Starzinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starzinger).

> The story revolves around the Princess of the Moon, Aurora and her three cyborg companions (Kugo, Djorgo, and Hakka) who must travel to the Great King planet and restore the Galaxy Energy in the year 2072. The universe was becoming more and more unbalanced as the Queen of the Great Planet grows older. Their adventure includes battling the starmen who are transformed from the unbalanced minerals and planets.

[image: Cover image] [image: English VHS Cover of "Spaceketeers" - "Spaceka" by Source. Licensed under Fair use via Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spaceka.jpg#/media/File:Spaceka.jpg]

You can see on the cover image the short fat green guy, the red and white suited guy with a headband, and a tall and skinny male character (blue outfit incidentally) as well as the princess.

Characters courtesy of Wikipedia:

> **Princess Aurora** - The only human among the main four characters. She is the last of the Moon people - Telepathy & psychic abilities and can channel Galaxy energy
>
> **Jan Kugo aka Jesse Dart** - A red suited cyborg. Became a cyborg to benefit and help humanity: demoted to menial jobs, he gained a bad temper. Based on the monkey-demon, Sun Wukong, of which "Kugo" is an anagram - Wields an Astro-lance that changes size and shoots lasers; in the second season, he can become larger or smaller at will
>
> **Sir Djorgo aka Arimos** - A blue suited cyborg. The most intelligent of the three. When in doubt, he asks his portable computer (which often displays a TOEI logo while elaborating a problem). Based on the water-demon, Sha Wujing, as Gojyo was the Japanese name of Wujing - Wields a Laser-trident with freeze abilities; occasionally shot missiles from his shoulders
>
> **Don Hakka aka Porkos** - A green suited cyborg, cheerful, hungry and the comedian. Based on the pig-demon, Zhu Bajie, as Hakkai is the Japanese name of Bajie and Porkos may refer to pork, as in pig - Swings a mace that turns into a flail and shoots rockets from his feet

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you provide some more details on the proposed answer?  Information such as the overall plot is very useful for the OP to make a determination